# Can't make the UrlManager Rules work in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I understand many variables outside what I can provide could be the problem, but I'm still asking if someone had this problem and could help.

Here's my UrlManager config in the components

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
        'showScriptName' => true,
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'site/index',
            'member' => 'site/login',
        ],
    ],
```

This url works:

```
http://exampler.com/web/index.php?r=site/login
```

This url returns a 404

```
http://example.com/web/index.php?r=member
```

**NOTE: ** I don't have any messy Nginx or Apache rules on my server like [this guy](https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37816-url-manager-rule-not-working/) had. My rules seem to be completely ignored, whatever I write in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rules` is ignored if you set `$enablePrettyUrl` to `false`. From `$rules` documentation:

> The rules for creating and parsing URLs when `$enablePrettyUrl` is `true`. This property is used only if `$enablePrettyUrl` is `true`.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager#$rules-detail

Comment: Thanks a lot friend, I'm upgrading from Yii1 to Yii2 and didn't expect this at all! +1 for the link with the exact place I missed!